# PDF/XLS Downloads and HTTP Headers on Android browsers

Tags: android, http-headers

Before you just refer me to another question, please read the HTTP headers I'm using, because I've tried many of the answers already to no avail.

On desktop browsers (other than IE which I can't test on Linux), downloads of PDF and XLS files that I'm attempting to offer up via a page are downloading just fine with the filename intact and the file size correct (everything perfect, basically).

However, on my Galaxy S3 (Jellybean), the files are downloading with the extension renamed to "htm" and the file size is 0 bytes. I've tried many mixtures of Content-Disposition and MIME types without success. Here are my headers:

```
Content-Disposition:attachment;filename="CustomRealtimeDetail-337EB300331F4762A4200CDE357E79E6.XLS"
Content-Length:175616
Content-Transfer-Encoding:Binary
Content-Type:application/octet-stream
```

EDIT: Noticed that `application/octetstream` was supposed to be `application/octet-stream`. This did not change the result.

The file is downloaded as `CustomRealtimeDetail-337EB300331F4762A4200CDE357E79E6.htm` with 0 bytes. I've tried making the `Content-Disposition` value

`attachment;filename="CustomRealtimeDetail-337EB300331F4762A4200CDE357E79E6.XLS";size=175616`

which just reverts to a problem I've alread overcome, which is the filename being the same as the page that generates the download (filesize not fixed).

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, according to [this question, its comments and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667362/jsf-streamed-download-on-android-device-returns-htm-file), returning a file download after a `POST` request is not handled well in Android browsers. Switching to a `GET` request completely resolved the issues.

Comment: If I could give you more pluses I would, been trying to solve this for hours!