# JSF download file on android device returns .htm file

Tags: android, jsf-2, download

I'm currently facing a problem when use JSF download file on mobile.

Everything works fine as long as I use my desktop browser, but as soon as I change to my mobile device,I get a .html file which contains the source code.

Here is my download method

```
public StreamedContent getDrawing() throws Exception {
    DocumentFile documentFile = (DocumentFile) getViewScope("documentFile");
    if (documentFile != null) {
        byte[] content = documentFileService.download(documentFile.getId());
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        externalContext.setResponseContentLength(content.length);
        StreamedContent content2 = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream,
                        URLEncoder.encode(documentFile.getFilename(), "UTF-8"));
        facesContext.responseComplete();
        return content2;
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is my downloadButton

```
<h:commandButton value="fileDownload">
      <p:fileDownload value="#{controller.drawing}"
         contentDisposition="attachment"></p:fileDownload>
      <f:ajax disabled="true" />
</h:commandButton>
```

I had saw this [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667362/jsf-streamed-download-on-android-device-returns-htm-file),but it can not solve my problem

Now I don't know how to solve this problem